# JSON/PHP - RIOT API - How to retrieve datasets

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

I am working on a big data project for university. I am using RIOT's API for league of legends. I want to collect all playernames with their division,tier,LP,wins from their api. Possibly 2500-10000 players per region. I failed to find a solution to this because its dumb to single query this every time.

How could this possibly be fixed? This is the code that will get all players from my own division in EUW. Maybe forloop?

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/31827832?api_key=key');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response, true);

    $json = array_pop($json);
    foreach($json[0]['entries'] as $entry){
        // print_r($json);
                echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ',' . $json[0]['tier'] . ',' . $entry['division'] . ',' . $entry['leaguePoints'] . ',' . $entry['wins'] . "<br/>";
            }
?>
```

The problem is, that this data can not be mixed with other data. I have to retrieve division by division and not all at the same time. Could the values be comma seperated by using fput_csv(); ?
I am unexperienced (have not done this type of job before) in this, any help is greatly appreciated. If you need additional information on this, please ask so. I hope we can work this out. I'm lost.

PS: the current code shown above is live at http://20ff.net

Comment: I don't get the problem, why don't you use a database?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to say? I can not follow you. I try to collect as much as possible to load them into datavisualization tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you don't know what to do with the data once you've fetched it, and you want to fetch it again later without having to call the API each time.

What you need is called "persistent storage", so you can store your data somewhere and be able to retrieve it easily and in a reasonable amount of time. There are many ways you could do that, a CSV file is one, as you've mentioned.

For this project, I recommend you use a real database (with PHP most people use MySQL), obviously we can't teach you that entire concept on SO, but you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Comment: Okay I do now understand you. But its unhuman to recall the api 50.000 times because riot api does not have a function to call all players information per region (i could understand that this load could kill their servers). I think I have to change plans because this is not going to work out properly. The storing of this data is not the problem, the problem is on how to get this data efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure how their API works, but there must be another way, as there are LoL sites who have a player database and I'm sure they didn't call the API 50k times.

Comment: I think its wise to contact them. Dan Caissy your help is greatly appreciated.